# grid.onDeleteRow() function not functioning/triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, processmaker

Can anyone help me why `grid.onDeleteRow()` is not functioning/triggering when I delete a row in my grid?

This is my code for triggering it.

```
$("#CCR_RF_GRD_DTLWRKINSTRUCTION").click(function(){          
          $("#CCR_RF_GRD_DTLWRKINSTRUCTION").onDeleteRow(function(){
              alert('A row was deleted');
          });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try only with [Document](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/JavaScript_Functions_and_Methods#grid.onDeleteRow)

```
$("#gridId").onDeleteRow(function(oGrid, aRow, rowIndex) { 
     //custom code here
})
```

function  `click` not fired!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("#yourbutton").on("click" , function() {
    //first delete all rows except for the first:
    var rows = $("#yourgrid").getNumberRows();
    for (var i=1; i < rows; i++) {
        $("#yourgrid").deleteRow();
    }
    //clear all fields in the grid:
    var aValues = $("#yourgrid").getValue();
    for (var i=1; i <= aValues[0].length; i++) {
        $("#yourgrid").setValue("", 1, i);
    }
} );
```

The above code deletes all the rows in your grid. If you only want 1, you can easily adapt it to delete just 1.